# x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match admission-controller.opa-istio.svc

Tags: kubernetes, istio, opa, mtls, cacerts

I m trying to enable mTLS in STRICT mode in Istio on my cluster with OPA, but when I try to create a pod, I m getting error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "istio.openpolicyagent.org": failed to call webhook: Post "https://admission-controller.opa-istio.svc:443/v0/data/istio/inject?timeout=10s": x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match admission-controller.opa-istio.svc
```

I have followed https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/issues/2477#issuecomment-646815932, but without progress.

Is anyone know where should look for a root cause?

I have created peer authentication with mode: STRICT for istio-system namespace, I am able to create pods in other namespaces, untouched by OPA (opa-istio-injection=enabled).

Comment: I am having the same error message using Kyverno as policy agent, when setting Kyverno up to create its own certificates. I haven't found an explanation yet, the certificates look OK.